# Headers are coming as empty in Kafka-python consumer

Tags: python, kafka-python

We are publishing header information using kafka-python like below:

```
def publish_message1(self, interface_time,  topic_name, value, success_call_back, error_call_back, key=None):
    if self.kafka_producer:
        value_bytes = bytes(value, encoding='utf-8')
        time_bytes = bytes(interface_time, encoding='utf-8')
        if key:
            key_bytes = bytes(key, encoding='utf-8')
        self.kafka_producer.send(topic_name, value=value_bytes, key=key_bytes, headers=[('Collection_Timestamp', time_bytes)])\
            .add_callback(success_call_back).add_errback(error_call_back)
    else:
        raise Exception("Connection not exists with Kafka to publish message")
```

The header info is showing in Kafka tool and it is getting published successfully.
When we are trying to consume, header=[] is coming as empty list.

Note: kafka-python version which we are using is "2.0.2"
Please let me know what is going wrong.